# how to share part of a Sharepoint List with item level permissions?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint form that creates an entry in a list, this list has item level permissions, I have admin so I can see all the entries and the users can only see their own. This is what i want.

I need to set up a calendar based on some of the entries in that list so i created a new view and assigned it a calendar type. That's fine for me (because i have admin) but not for sharing with the company.

so i would like to ask if any of you clever people can think of a way that i can do one of the following:

A: Share 3 columns (A Title,Date,company Name) from the original list.(remove item level permissions on just those columns)

B: Copy the entries automatically to a new list (so permissions do not matter)

C: anything else i cannot think of

Thanks

P.S. I have tried a lookup and this brought through one entry at a time manually so not worth it moving forward

Comment: SharePoint doesn't support the equivalent of `column-level permissions`, and "solutions" that try to mimic it usually are just relying on security through obscurity, leaving the underlying data still technically accessible. Your option `B` is probably best; use a Workflow on Item Create to insert an item into a second, unsecured List using the 3 columns of data you want to share. If your source items can be changed after the fact, you'll also want a WF to update its corresponding item in your shared list (link the two via Lookup).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any implementation limits?

One way to show this 3 columns in other way, not in list view web part in current list.
You can create web service, its web method, method will get data by 3 columns from your list under elevated privilege avoiding list item level permissions.
You can create some "thing" that will call web service method and display it. "Thing" can be Excel file, another list populated by some periodically running code, Report in SSRS or something else.

Or you can use workflow, timerjob or some other peridocally running code to move this 3 columns data to another source (list, sql table or something other). Create report on this source.

Or create your own web part that shows only 3 columns and get data under elevated privelege. Add this web part to any page.

May be other ways...